# How to implement viewpager2 with tab layout

Tags: android, kotlin

I know view pager and tab layout, but i want to display a tab on my screen, and each tab make up of a fragment. How can i do? I have try few approach but none of them work for me.

Comment: If just a fragment in shown in your activity what do you want to use viewpager? You can simply use tabLayout or bottomnavigationview and change/add fragments on item clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to use `TabLayout` and `ViewPager2`.

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

//create viewpageradaper class object
ViewPagerAdapter adapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    //adding fragments using adapter object
    adapter.AddFragment(new FirstFragment(), "Home");
    adapter.AddFragment(new SecondFragment(), "Friends");
    adapter.AddFragment(new ThirdFragment(), "Group");

    //set adapter into viewpager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set viewpager into tablayout
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Here's the [git repo](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/SmartTabLayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/viewpager/MainActivity.java)

Sometimes you might get an error with `ViewPager2` for auto import `import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;`

You have changed it to `ViewPager2` also.